# Dependent type with reference back (Scala)

Tags: scala, dependent-type, path-dependent-type

I'm playing with (path-)dependent types in Scala and stumbled upon a following scenario that I can't find a good solution for.
Assume that I want to have some hierarchy of dependent types and I want each of them to have a reference back to its "owner" object. I want this back-reference to be able to call some methods on the correct "owner" objects. What is the correct way to do it?

Here is a small example. There is a "base" trait `Outer` with a dependent type `Inner`. The base `Outer` trait defines some method `double` that works on the dependent type. There is also a specific class `ConcreteOuter` with a specific dependent class `ConcreteInner` that uses simple `Int` for the value.

```
trait Outer {
  outerSelf =>

  trait BaseInner {
    val outer: outerSelf.type = outerSelf

    def asDependent: outer.Inner         // #1
    //  def asDependent: outerSelf.Inner // #2
  }

  type Inner <: BaseInner

  def double(inner: Inner): Inner
}

class ConcreteOuter extends Outer {
  case class ConcreteInner(val v: Int) extends BaseInner {
    override def asDependent = this    
  }

  type Inner = ConcreteInner

  def createInner(v: Int): Inner = new ConcreteInner(v)

  override def double(inner: Inner): Inner = new ConcreteInner(2 * inner.v)
}
```

So far so good. Now assume I'd like to be able to call that `double` method in a context where I have only an instance of some `Inner` class but not the corresponding `Outer`-instance. For example, let's try to create another `double` method that just calls the original `Outer.double` in some other (independent) context:

```
object DepTest extends App {

  //def double(inner: Outer#Inner) = inner.outer.double(inner)           // #3

  def double(inner: Outer#Inner) = inner.outer.double(inner.asDependent) // #4


  val c1 = new ConcreteOuter
  val i1 = c1.createInner(123)
  val d1 = double(i1)
  println(d1)

}
```

This code compiles but requires a quite ugly hack of `asDependent`. If I use line #3 instead of line #4, the code doesn't compile. If I split the line #3 in a following way the code doesn't compile anymore

```
  def double(inner: Outer#Inner) = {
    val outer = inner.outer
    outer.double(inner.asDependent)
  }
```

Moreover, if I replace line #1 with line #2 even the `asDependent` hack stops working.

So it looks like somehow sometimes the compiler knows that the `outer` field of the `Inner` object and the "owner" object aka `outerSelf` is the same thing and sometimes it doesn't and it is not clear how to persuade the compiler when it doesn't recognize them as the same thing.

Is there a way to work this around? Or is this a totally wrong approach to my problem? (Obviously in the real world I'd like to create not just dumb proxies such as `DepTest.double` but some library of higher level functions such as `multiplyByPow2(val : Outer#Inner, exponent: Int)`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not very experienced with path-dependant types, but from what I can read from [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html), it seems that what happens is that `Outer` and `outerSelf.type` are not the same thing:

- `outerSelf.type` consists of either `outerSelf` or `null`
- `outerSelf: Outer` consists of only `outerSelf`

I think your problem is coming from here, but I have not enough knowledge on this to be able to help you more.